# Android. Остановить поток из другого потока

Tags: android

Аудиоплеер. Нажатие кнопки - запускает поток, а в нем музыку. Но как эту музыку остановить другой кнопкой stopButton?

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       Thread myThread;

        Button playButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
        Button stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);

        final Runnable runaudio =  new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                MediaPlayer media = new MediaPlayer();
                media = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.arena);
                media.start();}};


        playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view){

                Thread myThread = new Thread(runaudio);

                myThread.start();
            }
        });

        stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view){

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас не правильный подход к написанию плеера изначально. Проигрывание музыки должно выноситься в `Service` с пометкой `foreground()` и соответствующим уведомлением, иначе при нехватке ресурсов ваш плеер просто будет подчищен осью а пользователь будет негодовать.

И что уж говорить о том, что во время входящего вызова\каком либо другом действии плеер будет постоянно проигрываться. Если сейчас вы включите стандартный плеер, и ваш одновременно - они будут играть тоже одновременно.

Такого быть не должно.

Используйте сервис и данная проблема сама отпадёт.

Comment: а если в такой ситуации , но вместо плеера будет что другое, и понадобится так завершить поток, как мне можно будет это сделать?

Comment: Это так же плохая практика, есть метод **просящий** поток прекратить свою работу - но это совершенно не значит, что он обязательно это сделает. Посему рассчитывать на это не стоит, и я бы посоветовал вам искать другое решение.

Comment: создайте `volatile static` флаг в котором храните состояние плеера (проигрывать/не проигрывать). И проверяйте этот флаг.

Comment: @DimXenon только не `static`.

Comment: На уровне класса флаг, почему бы и нет? Если это будет именно плеер, с именно одним потоком проигрывания и одним - управления - вполне себе вариант. Если потоков много - можно коллекцию потокобезопасную использовать с флагами для каждого потока (карта с инструкциями и ключами-идентификаторами потоков).
В индивидуальном volatile флаге в каждом экземпляре плеера (для текущей задачи) я не вижу необходимости.